# Does C++ use static name resolution or dynamic name resolution?

Tags: c++, token-name-resolution

I have been reading about "Name resolution" in wikipedia ([Name resolution WIKI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_resolution_(programming_languages))) and it has been given in that that C++ uses "Static Name Resolution". If that is true then I couldn't figure out how C++ manages to provide "polymorphism" without using dynamic name resolution.

Can anyone please answer whether C++ uses "Static Name Resolution" or "Dynamic Name Resolution". If it is static, can you also explain how C++ provides polymorphism.

Comment: everything that is says dynamic polymorphism in c++ is related with  keyword "virtual". Read more about it.

Comment: It uses both. When you use abstract class use dynamic. For other things like templates, overloading, etc. it uses static.

Comment: @EdwinRodríguez I don't think *name resolution* is dynamic when you use an abstract class. Names are resolved at compile time.

Comment: To clear up, can anyone point out the mistake in below paragraph.

C and D are classes derived from B. B has a virtual function F and C, D overridden F in their implementations. x is a pointer to B and within my application x->F may be F of B,C  or D depending upon which object I've made x point to, which I can do depending on user input at runtime. If C++ uses static name resolution then x->F must be associated with only one entity i.e., either with F of B, C or D at compile time and should not change at runtime.

Comment: "If C++ uses static name resolution then x->F must be associated with only one entity i.e., either with F of B, C or D " No. This:  "If C++ uses static name resolution then and there is some code `x->F` then `B::F` must exist at compile time (but can be virtual)." Dynamic name resolution is 100% unrelated to dynamic dispatch (virtual functions)

Comment: I missed a part: `B::F` must exist at compile time _and cannot be changed while running_. (For virtual functions, the compiler generates a function with some dispatch code, which meets these requirements, it's not _actually_ replacing the function's name)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wikipedia's definition of name resolution is about how tokens are resolved into the names of constructs (functions, typenames, etc). Given that definition, C++ is 100% *static* with its name resolution. Every token that represents an identifier must be associated at compile-time with a specific entity.

C++ polymorphism is effectively cheating. The compiler can see that a static name resolves to a member function defined with the `virtual` keyword. If the compiler sees that the object you are calling this on is a dynamic object (ie: a pointer/reference to that type rather than a value of that type), the the compiler emits special code to call that function.

This special code does not change the *name* it resolves to. What it changes is the function that eventually gets called. That is not dynamic naming; that is dynamic function *dispatch*. The name gets resolved at compile-time; the function gets resolved at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

C++ use static name resolution because it renames each function to made each one have an unique.
That mean that the function `int foo(int bar)` will be known by the compiler as something like `_Z3fooi`, while `int foo(float bar)` will be known as something like `_Z3foof`.
This is what we call [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Name_mangling_in_C.2B.2B).

Comment: Edwin Rodriguez said in comments that abstract class uses dynamic name resolution, can you please clear that?

Comment: @pasha: He confused dynamic name resolution and dynamic dispatch. They're unrelated.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure name mangling is unrelated to static vs dynamic name resolution.